# Strange Google Appscript Error "Must only be whole numbers."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling

[image]

Amateur here.
An image above shows the `Logger.log()` being performed at the very end of the code. Yet somehow it gives off an Error that I cannot search up in Google (First time Googling can't help me, yikes)

Has anyone gotten a clue? A week ago, it worked perfectly fine before I temporarily abandon the project to focus on other real-life matters. Came back and re-ran the thing without any edit, and this error shows up.

Unfortunately I am very uncomfortable sharing the code - this Appscript utilizes a Google Spreadsheet that automates all the data and numbers for a "roleplaying game" that involves numbers related to money and purchasing. It's closest counterpart would be DnD, but it's much different, more embarrassing, and arguably more confusing when trying to explain it. If however I need to share the whole code for debugging purposes (200 lines), then I will.

Comment: Debugging techniques described in [mcve] will help you to get to the bottom of the problem. First step described there is "Restarting from scratch"- Create a new project/spreadsheet -> add only what is needed to reproduce the problem one by one. You may then produce a sample code, that accurately describes the problem without sharing your original code.

Comment: If you are anything like me,  then using TheMaster's suggestion will result in you finding the problem on your own.  If not you will at least have a good [mcve] to bring back to us.  Without it were pretty much in capable of assisting you.

Comment: Oh my... That's gonna take days to do because I have zero place on where to start on debugging. The debugger that came from App script pointed to no issues. I've already placed all points that I believe would be causing the problem and attached a `logger.log()` next to it to read out the variables, but all of the variables are picking up expected data and values, so the variables themselves isn't the problem.
I had tried deleting everything and run it empty, and it passed. Perhaps there *is* something that I missed that is causing the issue...
I will read further. Thanks guys

Comment: If I have to guess, that's a custom message in one of 1. your script files or 2. Data validations/"custom functions" in your spreadsheet throwing a custom error.

Comment: BINGO. Oh my god, it was the data validation throwing a custom error in my spreadsheet. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you think this issue will help others, consider adding a answer. See [answer]